# MSAL2 and .Net 5, keep getting 401 when calling server WebApi

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

First of all I've spent all day looking for someone with the same problem, found some clues but no definitive solution, so I'm posting this as a last resort.

I'm writing an Angular 12 application backed by a .Net 5 WebApi, two distinct environments. I'm using MSAL2 library on the Angular application and Microsoft.Identity.Web on the backend to configure Azure AD access.

I have undergone the process of configuring the two applications under Azure AD. I have ensured the following:

- On the API app, under "Expose an API", I have authorized the Angular app ClientId as a valid client.
- On the API app, under "Expose an API", I have created a default scope and then configured it in the Angular code in the "protectedResourceMap".
- On the Angular app, under "Authentication" I have added the authorization of type "Single Page Application", typed in the redirect URI and authorized ID tokens.
- On the Angular app, under "Api permissions", I have added the API app and then clicked the "Grant admin consent" so it has the green checkmark and it says "No" under "Required Admin consent".

On the Angular side everything works correctly. When I access the page with the MsalGuard I get redirected to MS Online login page, I then login with an organization account and I get redirected back to the SPA, the token is stored locally and I can see the page protected by the guard.

The problem I have is when I try to call a backend API. I've checked with the network panel and the Bearer token is getting added by the interceptor and sent with the request, but no matter what I always get a 401 unauthorized. I have already configured everything I've read online there is to configured - as stated in the bulleted list above - and I don't understand what's wrong.

I've also already found out that on the backend the property "ClientId" isn't really supposed to contain the guid but instead the audience, in the format "api://guid" so that's out of the way too. To be safe, I've tried both with and without the api:// and in both cases I get the 401.

The only talking error I get in the response is this:

> www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'api://my-guid' is invalid"

Of course I censored the guid, but there is the correct guid in the message.

Any help will be immensely appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I just found it and posted it as a solution a few minutes ago and yes, it solves my problem but it doesn't explain why. I'd rather know why I was getting that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to my problem here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62642601/232940

Even though I still don't know the cause. To sum it up: AddAuthorization() without parameters wasn't using the correct default policy, Jwt Bearer. The thing I cannot explain is a sample project I found, which was identical to mine, which was using AddAuthorization() without parameters and it worked. Same runtime, same nuget packages at the same version, same everything, and I tested them both with the same client code.

If someone can shed some light on this mystery...