# .NET Core JWTBearerAuth returning "Unauthorized"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to add auth to my .NET Core 3.1 application, however each attempt to use the returned JWT results in `401 Unauthorized`. I've gone through a few steps to debug:

1. I've confirmed that the JWT that my `authenticate` endpoint returns is valid, using [this online validator](https://jwt.io/).
2. I've re-ordered my `UseRouting()`, `UseAuthentication()`, `UseAuthorization()`, and `UseEndpoints()` to every possible order.
3. I've disabled both `audience` and `issuer` validation entirely for the time being.

Can someone identify where I've gone wrong, or at the very least, provide some method of properly debugging so I can track the issue down? Thanks. Code below.

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(options => { 
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("thisismycustomSecretkeyforauthentication");
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = "issuer",
                ValidAudience = "audience",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
            };
        });

    services
        .AddControllers();
        .AddMvc(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = false; });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app
        .UseStaticFiles()
        .UseHsts()
        .UseHttpsRedirection()
        .UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=App}/{action=Index}/{id?}"))
        .UseRouting()
        .UseAuthentication()
        .UseAuthorization()
        .UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseSpa(spa => spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("https://localhost:22010"));
}
```

**AuthController.cs**

```cs
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request)
    {
        if (request.Username != "test" || request.Password != "admin")
            return Unauthorized();

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("thisismycustomSecretkeyforauthentication"));
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken
        (
            issuer: null,
            audience: null,
            claims: new Claim[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, request.Username) },
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(tokenKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );
        var tokenResponse = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return Ok(tokenResponse);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Do()
    {
        return Ok("Done!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication setup looks fine, and your middleware order is per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order).
Based on the code provided you seem to be missing the actual Authorization options. This is similar to the issue [solved in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784211/jwt-token-error-401-unauthorized-in-net-core-3-1).

Comment: This seems to have worked! That said, I thought this was being applied globally by my implementation of `AddAuthentication`. Any ideas how I can apply this to all authorization attributes?

Comment: You currently only setting up Authentication in your Startup class. You can extend this setup with services.AddAuthorization( ... to do the same for your Authorization.

Comment: Spot on, thank you so much. I've referenced [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes) to configure the default globally.